# How to call Stored Procedures and defined functions in MySQL with Slick 3.0

Tags: mysql, scala, slick-3.0

I have defined in my db something like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION fun_totalInvestorsFor(issuer varchar(30)) RETURNS INT
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LOYAL3_SHARED_HOLDER_ID) 
      FROM stocks_x_hldr
      WHERE STOCK_TICKER_SIMBOL = issuer AND
            QUANT_PURCHASES > QUANT_SALES);
END;
```

Now I have received an answer from Stefan Zeiger (Slick lead) redirecting me here: [User defined functions in Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/userdefined.html?highlight=user%20defined%20functions)

I have tried (having the following object in scope):

```
lazy val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb",
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", user = "dev", password = "root")
val totalInvestorsFor = SimpleFunction.unary[String, Int]("fun_totalInvestorsFor")
totalInvestorsFor("APPLE") should be (23)
```

Result: `Rep(slick.lifted.SimpleFunction$$anon$2@13fd2ccd fun_totalInvestorsFor, false) was not equal to 23`

I have also tried while having an application.conf in src/main/resources like this:

```
tsql = {
  driver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
  db {
    connectionPool = disabled
    driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"
  }
}
```

Then in my code with `@StaticDatabaseConfig("file:src/main/resources/application.conf#tsql")`

```
tsql"select fun_totalInvestorsFor('APPLE')" should be (23)
```

Result: `Error:(24, 9) Cannot load @StaticDatabaseConfig("file:src/main/resources/application.conf#tsql"): No configuration setting found for key 'tsql'
        tsql"select fun_totalInvestorsFor('APPLE')" should be (23)
        ^`

I am also planning to call stored procedures that return one tuple of three values, via `sql"call myProc(v1)`.as[(Int, Int, Int)]

Any ideas?

EDIT: When making 
     `sql""""SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LOYAL3_SHARED_HOLDER_ID)
             FROM stocks_x_hldr
             WHERE STOCK_TICKER_SIMBOL = issuer AND
                   QUANT_PURCHASES > QUANT_SALES""".as[(Int)]`
results in `SqlStreamingAction[Vector[Int], Int, Effect]` instead of the suggested `DBIO[Int]` (from what I infer) suggested by the documentation

Comment: Try `totalInvestorsFor("APPLE") should be LiteralColumn(23)`

Comment: `Rep(slick.lifted.SimpleFunction$$anon$2@2d710f1a fun_totalInvestorsFor, false) was not equal to Rep(LiteralNode 23 (volatileHint=false))`

Comment: Its a database function. It needs to go through the database inside of a query to be evaluated. Otherwise it is just an expression tree of what should happen on the db side, not the result.

Comment: your sql"..." thing should be a DBIO[Vector[Int]]... which I think it is, because SqlStreamingAction is a subtype of DBIOAction, which is aliased as DBIO

Comment: Try calling db.run on it and see what you get

Comment: With the following configuration `lazy val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb",
    driver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$", user = "root", password = "root")` and calling it with ` val f = db.run(dbio).value.get.get` I'm getting None option, are the db parameters ok for MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

I've been running into exactly the same problem for the past week. After some extensive research ([see my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291124/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-and-get-return-value-in-slick-using-scala?noredirect=1#comment48713015_30291124), I'll be adding a complete description of what I've done as a solution), I decided it can't be done in Slick... not strictly speaking.

But, I'm resistant to adding pure JDBC or Anorm into our solution stack, so I did find an "acceptable" fix, IMHO.

The solution is to get the session object from Slick, and then use common JDBC to manage the stored function / stored procedure calls. At that point you can use any third party library that makes it easier... although in my case I wrote my own function to set up the call and return a result set.

```
val db = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource)
var response: Option[GPInviteResponse] = None

db.withSession {
    implicit session => {
        // Set up your call here... (See my other post for a more detailed
        // answer with an example:
        // procedure is eg., "{?=call myfunction(?,?,?,?)}"
        val cs = session.conn.prepareCall(procedure.toString)
        // Set up your in and out parameters here
        // eg. cs.setLong(index, value)
        val result = cs.execute()
        val rc = result.head.asInstanceOf[Int]

        response = rc match {
            // Package up the response to the caller
        }
    }
}
db.close()
```

I know that's pretty terse, but as I said, see the other thread for a more complete posting. I'm putting it together right now and will post the answer shortly.

Comment: This is much, much less declarative and less FP than doing so with previous _interpolation_ and having an implicit Session in scope, via previous versions of Slick, I think I'm going back to that. Thanks Zac!